# How can I release an .exe that could be run by others?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe

I wrote a currency converter program using C# in Visual Studio. The program compiled and works fine.

I want to see how it performs on other people's machines, so I shared the .exe file under my project/bin/Debug with my friend via Google drive. However, it could not run due to

> Windows is protecting your PC

error (the message shows it is an recognized application.)

What is the appropriate way to share my app?

Comment: Try using Inno. :)
[Inno Website](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

Comment: You might try to build the application in Release mode. If that doesn't fix the issue, try using ClickOnce.

Answer (score 0):

**Turn off Windows protected your PC**

To turn the SmartScreen feature off on the start screen of Windows 8 do the following:

1. Make sure you are on the desktop. If you are not, press the Windows key.
2. Press Windows-C or move your mouse cursor to the upper or lower right corner of the screen
3. Select Settings > Control Panel from the menu.
4. Select System and Security and on the next page Action Center.
5. Click on the **Change Windows SmartScreen settings** link on the left sidebar.

[image: smart screen settings]

The following three options are available:

1. Get administrator approval before running an unrecognized app from the Internet (recommended)
2. Warn before running an unrecognized app, but don't require administrator approval.
3. Don't do anything (turn off Windows SmartScreen).

The third option turns off the feature completely so that you do not see the Windows protected your PC messages anymore when you run unrecognized applications on your operating system.

There is a faster way to go to the setting. Press Windows-W to open the Settings search app on the start screen. Enter smartscreen here and select the only option that pops ups (Change SmartScreen settings). This opens the Action Center control panel applet from where you can select to change SmartScreen options on the left.

Source: [link](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/11/03/turn-off-windows-protected-your-pc-windows-smartscreen/)

Comment: Are you saying that every single person that uses the OP's app is going to have to do this? Besides the third option is extremely dangerous and should never be used

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, agreed, third option is never to be used. Since its an sample application, this option will help to proceed OP's testing.